# Specified columns error

Tags: r, dt

I'm using 'data.table' package and trying to use the formatting prints functions of the package. 
I want to present some of the columns as Currency and some as Percentage,
But I got an error when specifying the table column names.
my data :

str(dt) :

[image: str(dt):]

when trying to apply:

```
dt %>% formatCurrency(c('A','E'))
```

> "Error in name2int(name, names, rownames) :    You specified the
>   columns: A, E, but the column names of the data are "

edit: this issue can be re-created by:

```
tmp = data.table('A' = rep(1:10),'B' = rep(11:20))

tmp %>% formatPercentage(c('A','B'),2)
```

Comment: Please provide a plain text example using `dput` for example. It will be easier for SO community to help you

Comment: This is my first post so apologies if it's a bit messy. To be honest I never heard about dput. I added a 2 line code which is re-creating the issue I mentioned, do you think it is neccersy to add more than that? I feel like this isn't a very specfic case (in terms of the kind of table or code I'm running)

Comment: This is how to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I get the same error with a data.frame. From `?formatCurrency` the opject it accepts is a "*a table object created from datatable()*" which is not the same as a `data.table` or a `data.frame`. In either way, it is not data.table related error. You need to read the docs. Also, you need to specify that `formatCurrency` is from the `DT` package.

Comment: Yes, `DT::formatCurrency` is a wrapper of JS code for formatting. It does not work on data.table directly. The error message could be improved to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing packages...  `formatPercentage()` is from `DT`, you make the data with `data.table` and then use `%>%` from `dplyr`

Why not do it all under the `tidyverse` / `dplyr` umbrella?

```
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- data.frame(A = rep(1:10), B = rep(11:20))

tmp %>% mutate(A = scales::percent(A), B = scales::dollar(B))
```

you can change the currency of `dollar()` using `dollar_format()`

Comment: Thanks! 
Your comment led me to my mistake- 
using 'data.table' instead of  'datatable'. 

the pipe & the formatPercentage() works well when creating the table :

' tmp <- datatable(A = rep(1:10), B = rep(11:20)) '
' tmp %>% formatPercentage(c('A','B'),2) '